# Sql grandparent-parent-child relationships

Tags: sql

I have 3 tables t1,t2,t3.
t1 is the grandpa, t2 (the parent) has a FK to the id of t1 and t3 (the child) has a FK to the id of the t2. My problem is that I want the t3 to has also the id of t1 as a FK.
How can I do this? The reason that I want to have the id of t1 to t3 is that I do not want every time I need to find the grandpa of a t3 record to make a join query with t2.

Comment: Don't be afraid of joins.

Answer (score 0):

Approach 1:

Create a user-defined function which will give you the grand parent and use that in computed column in your child table to store grandparent permanently in child's table. No joins or foreign key required.

Approach 2:

Create a scalar function which will take child and return grandparent, use that in select wherever required.

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
create table T1
(
   T1Id int primary key
)
create table T2
(
  T1Id int references T1,
  T2Id int,
  constraint pk_T2
    primary key (T1Id, T2Id)
)
create table T3
(
  T1Id int,
  T2Id int,
  T3Id int,
  constraint pk_T3
    primary key (T1Id, T2Id, T3Id),
  constraint fk_T3_t2
    foreign key (T1Id,T2Id) references T2
)
```

Now T3 has T1Id, and has an optimized access path to find all the T3's for a particular T1Id, or a particular (T1Id,T2Id).  And you don't need extra indexes to support your foreign keys, as you do with the alternative designs.